# How to clear the "date last opened" attribute on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, finder, file-attributes, macos-bigsur

I am trying to clear this extended attribute for all the files located in the Recents smart folder. They are ordered by the "date last opened" attribute. I am trying to clear this attribute so that the files no longer show in recents.

So far I have been able to set the date using

```
xattr -w "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate" "01/01/2000" my file
```

This worked once and is no longer working.

Additionally I used

```
xattr -d "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate" "01/01/2000" myfile
```

This worked! But just once for one file. Strangely it does not seem to be working any more.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an attribute, use the `-d` flag and the attribute name:

```
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate myfile
```

Notice, I am not providing a date (`"01/01/2000"`)

Comment: Hi, yes, I accidentally provided the date... But this code doesn't seem to work consistently. It works sometimes but not others.

Comment: Take a look at this answer (`xattr` on macOS), specifically the section about multiple versions of xattr. Solutions which are detailed here may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616002

Comment: I'm getting `No such xattr: com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate` on Ventura.